# How to calculate the XOR probability

Tags: probability

I have some questions regarding this problem:

> Arthur and Dutch are planned together to go out the next Saturday which is predicted to be sunny.
>   There is a probability of 0.4 that Dutch wears sunglasses the day they are supposed to meet. The probability that Arthur wears sunglasses on the same day is 0.7 if Dutch wears sunglasses and 0.35 if he does not.

The question is:

> What is the probability that exactly one of them wear sunglasses on the day they are supposed to meet?

Let A be Arthur wears glasses, and D be Dutch wears glasses.

Is it $P(A \oplus D)$? I can think of two formula, but I'm not sure about the difference:

1. $P(A \cap \bar{D}) + P(D \cap \bar{A})= P(A \cup D)-P(A \cap D) = 0.33$
2. $P(A \cap \bar{D}) + P(D \cap \bar{A})= P(A | \bar{D})P(\bar{D}) + P(D|\bar{A})P(\bar{A}) = 0.35*0.6+0.235294...*0.51$

However, they yield different results.
In the second, I used this formula to calculate $P(\bar{A})$

$P(A) = P(A | \bar{D})P(\bar{D}) + P(A|D)P(D) = 0.6*0.35+0.4*0.7 = 0.49$
$P(\bar{A}) = 0.51$

$P(D|\bar{A}) = P(D \cap \bar{A})/P(\bar{A}) = (P(D)-P(A \cap D))/0.51 = (0.4-0.28)/0.51=0.235294...$

Which solution is true, and what is the problem with different results. I doubt the second one is correct because of the result.

Comment: It seems to me that both results agree. Did you try computing the expression you get from the second approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The results agree. It helps to work in fractions rather than decimals. Then $0.235\dots$ becomes $\frac{12}{51}$, so the second method returns $\frac{21}{100}+\frac{12}{51}\frac{51}{100}=\frac{33}{100}$.

You might have found $P(D\cap\overline{A})$ easier to compute as $P(\overline{A}|D)P(D)=0.3\times 0.4=0.12$.

Comment: Thanks, I used the venn diagram for the second but the Bayes rule also works.